# Text style code shown as plain text in autocomplete form in PHP AJAX JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax, autocomplete

I'm programming a page in PHP which retrieves a word from external txt document with autocomplete function. The words in the external document are written as plain text, each word in new line. When a user inputs letters in the text field, it filters out matching words in real-time from external file and lists them immediately like an autocomplete form.

I have one issue - some words in the list have extra explanations beside and have to be shown in the results in italic to differentiate.
Example: "`Pineapple *(fruit)*`"  But the autocomplete function lists the words as plain text without applying the code.

I indicated style codes for the word "fruit", such as `<i>`, `<em>`. However they don't get recognized by the autocomplete function as a code or style, but as a plain text, so the words are shown as "`<i>fruit</i>`" or "`<em>fruit</em>`" instead of "*fruit*" - in italic. Shortly: these codes aren't detected or applied to the text. Below is the example image:

[image: Example]

I input the important part of the code:

```
function getautocompleteoptions($input) {
    $lists = getLists();
    $autocompleteoptions = filterwords($lists, $input);
    return $autocompleteoptions;
    }

//AJAX
if (isset($_GET['autocomplete'])) {
    $input = $_GET['autocomplete'];
    $autocompleteoptions = getautocompleteoptions($input);
    echo json_encode($autocompleteOptions);
}
```

Was told to to add another function to match the style and apply it. Added this function before Ajax:

```
    function usestyle($word) { 
    if (preg_match('/\{(\w+)\}(.*?)\{\/\1\}/', $word, $matches)) {
        $style = $matches[1];
        $content = $matches[2];
        return '<em>' . $content . '</em>';
    } else {
        return $word; // Regular style
    }
    }
```

It also didn't have any effect - still the style code shown on the screen as a plain text.

Though I know some, still not nerd in web programming so I would appreciate if you can give a bit detailed advice. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide the piece of code that you display the result?

Comment: I would recommend getting the list and then echoing each of the matching word inside a loop.

Comment: Problem isn't on server it must be something to with your client side code jQuery/react or whatever

Comment: @AriadniMak added the last part of the code